# How can I add an array of strings from a separate method to a JList model?

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, jlist

I have a JList model that wants me to specify the index ("array[i]" not just "array") in my array of strings in order to add it as an element. Otherwise it just returns hash code. How can I add it if it comes from a separate method? The only way I found was to just copy-paste the method's code every time I needed it which doesn't seem like a good solution.

This is where I want to add it:

```
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileFinder.thing().length; i++) {
        model.addElement(fileFinder.thing());
    }
    JList list = new JList(model);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```

This is what the method looks like:

```
    public class fileFinder {
    public static String[] thing() {
        File file = new File(".\\at9snfsbs");
        File[] files = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".at9")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        String[] fileNames = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileNames[i] = files[i].getName();
        }

        return fileNames;
    }
}
```

I'm by no means a good or experienced programmer so any help would be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
String[] things = fileFinder.thing();
for (String thing : things) {
    model.addElement(thing);
}
JList list = new JList(model);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```

You can also use the long version of the for loop like this:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
String[] things = fileFinder.thing();
for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    model.addElement(things[i]);
}
JList list = new JList(model);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```